# Showing entries for light switch

Tags: entries, database, entry-type, query, lightswitch

So I have three light switches on my blog: 'featured', 'required reading' and 'skills'.

I got the featured section to work with this code:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries
    .section(['etiquette', 'style','culture','reviews'])
    .where('featured' == 1)
    .orderBy('id desc')
    .limit(4)
    .all()
%}
```

but when I went to do the reading section I used this code:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries
    .section([
        'etiquette',
        'style',
        'culture'
    ])
    .where('requiredReading' == 1)
    .orderBy('id desc')
    .limit(12)
    .all()
%}
```

but i get all the stories with reading and featured switches on. I checked the database and the required reading field is 0. How can I get just the required reading or can you not use more than one lightswitch?

Answer (score 3):

Try rewriting your element query like so...

`craft.entries
.section(['etiquette','style','culture'])
.requiredReading(true)
.orderBy('id desc')
.limit(12)
.all()`

In Craft you can do queries against fields in this way. The `where()` isn't necessary for what you're trying to achieve.